# Page have reloaded all time when I try to get her via cURL

Tags: php, node.js, parsing, curl, http-headers

So, I need to parse some content from http://israelbar.org.il, and using for this cURL, but when I run script - tab in browser all time reload, and nothing showed.

```
$browser = curl_init();
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); //times out after 11s
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); //times out after 51s
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($browser, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
$retVal = curl_exec ($browser);
curl_close ($browser);
unset($browser);
return $retVal;
```

Also, I try NodeJS, and get some, unknown for me listing of JS code in console.

I think, that main problem - it's different headers, and I must send the same headers via cURL, like a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing the working browser request with a tool like Fiddler? (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Also, can you clarify the language and set up you are using (looks like PHP?) And which 'tab' is reloading (is it your own site's?)

Other things to try:
 - Call a site you know will work first -- to ensure your code is correct
 - Adjust the timeout values to much larger values when testing

Comment: Thank you, Iain!
Yes, I'm using PHP (5.6). Code work fine, because another sites I can parse without any problems. 
I seen in headers that: Server:Reblaze Secure Web Gateway
And I think, that parse this site - it's a really difficult task, because it has a security software.